# Decrypting a PGP File from SFTP Server

Tags: marketing-cloud, encryption, crypto, decrypt, pgp

**Problem**

The client that I am working with is asking us to encrypt (Using PGP or GPG) files from marketing cloud and insert them onto an SFTP Server. Then, we should create a separate Node JS Application to grab the encrypted files and decrypt them. The problem I am running into is that I cannot find a suitable package so decrypt these files.

**Things I've Tried**
While programs exist to decrypt PGP files, I cannot find a package within the node package manager to do this. I have tried using [OpenPGP](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs) to decrypt these files but am unable to do so because Salesforce provides basic PGP encryption and not armored PGP encryption. I have also looking into [GPG](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpg) but that also did not provide any solution.

Has anyone run into a similar problem and were they able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out a solution to this using OpenPGP. I read a little bit more into their documentation and tried a couple different things I saw from their solutions.

I read the file in using `fs.readFileSync` and then used the `.read` function instead of the `.readArmored`. Other than that, I simply followed their basic example and pulled from that to initiate my privateKey